# AWS s3 copy hangs after large transfer when run in Ansible from Terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, ansible, terraform

I'm provisioning a large (r5.2xl) ec2 instance with `Terraform`, and configuring using `Ansible`. The application's install kit, and data - 640GB, are in an S3 bucket in my region that I have full access to. My first play uses the shell module to invoke the aws s3 cp --recursive cli to move the data to a non-root, 2TB EBS volume, mounted at /opt/app.

I can tell that the task transfers all the data, but it never ends. My only symptom is a process on the target machine running AnsiballZ_command.py. It doesn't look like it's doing much, and killing it doesn't affect the playbook, or the Terraform process. I've validated that I can run the transfer directly from cli on the provisioned machine, and when I move the playbooks there, they run successfully too.

The only option at this point is to kill the TF, hosing my state file and forcing a manual tear down.

What's the proper way to do this?

My TF (v0.11.11) code, minus the connection info, run from a null_resource:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline      = ["sudo apt install --yes cowsay"]
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      sleep 30;
         >spookykat.ini;
         echo "[spookykat]" | tee -a spookykat.ini;
         echo "${element(aws_instance.this.*.private_ip, count.index)} ansible_user=${local.ec2-user} ansible_private_key_file=${var.private_key_path}" | tee -a spookykat.ini;
      export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False;
      export ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=true;
      export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH="./ansible_log.log";
      export ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT=true;
         ansible-playbook -u ${local.ec2-user} --private-key ${var.private_key_path} -i spookykat.ini ${path.root}/playbooks/spookykat_configure.yml --extra-vars @${local.extra-vars-json}
    EOT
  }
```

And, my Ansible task:

```
    - name: Sync Spatialkat S3 to local
      shell: >
              aws s3 cp --recursive s3://{{ src_bucket }}/{{ root_path }}/{{ release }}
              {{ dest_path }}/{{ root_path }}/{{ release }}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to SO. While this question is at grave risk of closure for not being on topic, I wanted to point out that with `awscli` being written in python it is unlikely to be the best choice for moving around 640GB worth of data. You may have better luck with [rclone](https://rclone.org/s3/) or a similar native, high performance utility. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response and rclone tip. I targeted TF because the process works without it. In my latest experiment, I refactored to send the playbooks to the provisioned host, then remote-exec run it. The first two tries ran perfectly.